# How can I create multidimensional arrays in Perl?

Tags: perl, arrays, data-structures, multidimensional-array

I am a bit new to Perl, but here is what I want to do:

```
my @array2d;
while(<FILE>){
  push(@array2d[$i], $_);
}
```

It doesn't compile since `@array2d[$i]` is not an array but a scalar value.

How should I declare @array2d as an array of array?

Of course, I have no idea of how many rows I have.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

To make an array of arrays, or more accurately an array of arrayrefs, try something like this:

```
my @array = ();
foreach my $i ( 0 .. 10 ) {
  foreach my $j ( 0 .. 10 ) {
    push @{ $array[$i] }, $j;
  }
}
```

It pushes the value onto a dereferenced arrayref for you.  You should be able to access an entry like this:

```
print $array[3][2];
```

Comment: You can also access as $array[3][2] -- the arrow isn't needed between successive [n] or {key} indexes of multi-level data structures.

Comment: You're right, thanks for the info.  I'm going to update the answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 8):

Change your "push" line to this:

```
push(@{$array2d[$i]}, $_);
```

You are basically making $array2d[$i] an array by surrounding it by the @{}...  You are then able to push elements onto this array of array references.

Comment: Good explanation. To clarify further, $array2d[$i] is an array reference. In @{$array2d[$i]}, the {} block returns the array reference and the @ sigil dereferences it as an array. I point this out to make it clear that the braces are a bare block, not a device for subverting precedence.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying my explanation - I knew that it worked, but I never knew the technical reasons behind it.  Thanks!

Comment: No, they're a dereferencing block, not a bare block.  In perl -wle'{ 1 if @{;last}; print "in" } print "out"', the last sees the outer, truly bare block, not the inner block.

Answer (score 6):

Have a look at [perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html) and [perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html) to see how to make nested data structures, like arrays of arrays and hashes of hashes.  Very useful stuff when you're doing Perl.

Answer (score 3):

There's really no difference between what you wrote and this:

```
@{$array2d[$i]} = <FILE>;
```

I can only assume you're iterating through files.

To avoid keeping track of a counter, you could do this:

```
...
push @array2d, [ <FILE> ];
...
```

That says 1) create a reference to an empty array, 2) storing all lines in FILE, 3) push it onto `@array2d`.

Answer (score 0):

Another simple way is to use a hash table and use the two array indices to make a hash key:

```
$two_dimensional_array{"$i $j"} = $val;
```

Comment: There's actually some ancient syntactic sugar for that: http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Multi-dimensional-array-emulation - so you can just do `$two_dim_array{$i,$j} = $val`

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to store a file in an array you can also do this:

```
fopen(FILE,"<somefile.txt");
@array = <FILE>;
close (FILE);
```