# Building and printing a multidimensional list in Perl without looping

Tags: perl, multidimensional-array

The top answer in this post: [How can I create a multidimensional array in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/317310/how-can-i-create-multidimensional-arrays-in-perl) suggests building a multi-dimensional array as follows:

```
my @array = ();
foreach my $i ( 0 .. 10 ) {
  foreach my $j ( 0 .. 10 ) {
    push @{ $array[$i] }, $j;
  }
}
```

I am wondering if there is a way of building the array more compactly and avoiding the nested loop, e.g. using something like:

```
my @array = ();
my @other_array = (0 ... 10);
foreach my $i ( 0 .. 10 ) {
    $array[$i] = @other_array; # This does not work in Perl
  }
}
```

Does Perl support any syntax like that for **building** multi-dimensional arrays without nested looping?

Similarly, is there a way to **print** the multidimensional array without (nested) looping?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid nested looping? These sorts of questions miss the point. What are you trying to accomplish and why doesn't this work for you? These oversimple examples remove all the cruft to show you the central part of the problem. Don't let the simple data make you think otherwise.

Comment: Why the downvote? Thanks @briandfoy, not sure who downvoted the question, but your comment (e.g. `"these sorts of questions miss the point"`) seems to judge my approach to learning the language, and/or the *reasons* that lead me to ask the question, rather than the question itself. I am just trying to learn the features I can use in Perl, for example to make my code more readable or to avoid typing extra code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is more than one way to do it:

### Generating

**[`push`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/push.html) accepts `LIST`s**

```
my @array;
push @{$array[$_]}, 0 .. 10 for 0 .. 10;
```

Alternative syntax:

```
my @array;
push @array, [ 0 .. 10 ] for 0 .. 10;
```

**[`map`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) eye-candy**

```
my @array = map { [ 0 .. 10 ] } 0 .. 10;
```

Alternative syntax:

```
my @array = map [ 0 .. 10 ], 0 .. 10;
```

### Printing

**With minimal looping**

```
print "@$_\n" for @array;
```

**On Perl 5.10+**

```
use feature 'say';
say "@$_" for @array;
```

**With more formatting control**

```
print join( ', ', @$_ ), "\n" for @array;   # "0, 1, 2, ... 9, 10"
```

**"No loops"**  (The loop is hidden from you)

```
use Data::Dump 'dd';
dd @array;
```

**`Data::Dumper`**

```
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper \@array;
```

---

Have a look at [`perldoc perllol`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perllol.html) for more details

Comment: This is a very interesting solution. Can this be applied to **printing** the array as well? (i.e. print the array without looping)

Comment: Thanks Zaid! This answer is probably the most complete one now. However I can't get the printing to work. I am creating a multidimensional array iteratively, looping with the variable $i copying data from another array called sample: `$array[$i] = \@sample[1..$#sample];`. This seems to work well for building the array, but when I print it with `print "@$_\n" for @array`; I get the error: `Not an ARRAY reference`. Any thoughts why?

Comment: @roseck : You can't take a reference to a list slice like that, so you'll need to use `$array[$i] = [ @sample[1..$#sample] ];` instead

Answer (score 2):

You are close, you need a reference to the other array

```
my @array;  # don't need the empty list
my @other_array = (0 ... 10);
foreach my $i ( 0 .. 10 ) {
    $array[$i] = \@other_array;
    # or without a connection to the original
    $array[$i] = [ @other_array ];
    # or for a slice
    $array[$i] = [ @other_array[1..$#other_array] ];
  }
}
```

You can also make anonymous (unnamed) array reference directly using square braces `[]` around a list.

```
my @array;
foreach my $i ( 0 .. 10 ) {
    $array[$i] = [0..10];
  }
}
```

Edit: printing is probably easiest using the postfix `for`

```
print "@$_\n" for @array;
```

for numerical multidimensional arrays, you can use [`PDL`](http://pdl.perl.org). It has several constructors for different use cases. The one analogous to the above would be `xvals`. Note that PDL objects overload printing, so you can just print them out.

```
use PDL;
my $pdl = xvals(11, 11);
print $pdl;
```

Comment: Or `$array[$i] = [ @other_array ];` if the arrays should be independent.

Comment: @choroba, yeah, that would prevent changes to `@other_array` from propagating back to the `@array`.

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks Joel! Just wondering, is there a way to **print** the array without looping as well? (or with minimal looping)

Comment: You can print the whole thing with modules like [`Data::Dumper`](http://p3rl.org/Data::Dumper) or [`Data::Printer`](http://p3rl.org/Data::Printer)

Comment: Great, but I can't get the printing to work. I am creating a multidimensional array iteratively, looping with the variable `$i` copying data from another array `sample`:  `$array[$i] = \@sample[1..$#sample];`. This seems to work for building the array, but when I print with `print "@$_\n" for @array;` I get the error: `Not an ARRAY reference`. Any thoughts why?

Comment: I'm not sure what happens when you take a reference to a slice.

Comment: Thanks Joel. The downvote wasn't me. Thanks for letting me know that I was creating a reference to a slice, if I could accept two answers I would accept both!