# Collecting subarrays from multidimensional arrays in Perl

Tags: perl, multidimensional-array, slice

Say I build the following multidimensional array:

```
my @array;  # don't need the empty list
my @other_array = (0 ... 10);

foreach my $i ( 0 .. 10 ) {
$array[$i] = [ @other_array[1..$#other_array] ];
}
```

I would like to collect a "column" of this multidimensional array into a separate array,

For example, if I want to collect the items in the first column, I would like something like

```
my @other_array = ();
@other_array = $array[:][1]; # This does NOT work in Perl
```

Is there a way to do this in Perl without looping?

Eventually what I want to do is get the array of `max` of each column of my multidimensional array.

PS: This question is inspired by this other question: [Building and printing a multidimensional list in Perl without looping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12392127/building-and-printing-a-multidimensional-list-in-perl-without-looping/12392340#12392340).

Comment: Btw, the `[1..$#other_array]` bit in your loop is a bit more verbose than needed. You can just drop it and have just `[ @other_array ]`, which means the same thing.

Comment: @zostay : Not quite. The first element (index 0) is omitted in the slice

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want:

```
my @other_array = map { $_->[1] } @array;
```

Another language might have a special syntax for this operation, but it would still be performing a loop under the hood.

Comment: I don't like dropping the block syntax. I prefer to keep the `{}` around. However, that's mostly a personal preference.

Comment: My personal preference is that the simpler and more like normal code something looks, the better. But as you say, it is purely cosmetic.

Answer (score 4):

Befriend [`map`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html):

```
my @other_array = map $array[$_][1], 0 .. $#array;
```

The [Slices section in `perldoc perllol`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perllol.html#Slices) has more examples.

Answer (score 2):

For your example, this might be an overkill solution, but assuming your are planing to do this with huge multi-dimensional arrays (matrix's), use `PDL` and do a `transpose` then slice out the desired line.