# multidimensional array: argument isn't numeric in array element

Tags: perl, multidimensional-array

OS: AIX

Shell: KSH

Following the accepted answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/317310/how-can-i-create-multidimensional-arrays-in-perl) I have created an multimensional array. Only, I get an error while trying to print the content of the array.

**Error:**

```
Argument "content of $pvid" isn't numeric in array element at...
```

**The script:**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Term::ANSIColor;
my @arrpvid = ();

print colored( sprintf("%-10s %9s %8s %8s %8s", 'PVID', 'AIX', 'VIO', 'VTD', 'VHOST'), 'green' ), "\n";
foreach my $pvid (`lspv | awk '{print \$2'}`) {
        foreach my $hdaix (`lspv | awk '{print \$1'}`) {
                chomp $pvid;
                chomp $hdaix;
                push @{ $arrpvid[$pvid] }, $hdaix;
        }
}

print $arrpvid[0][0];
```

**Some explanation**:

Basically I want to print 5 variables of 5 different arrays next to each other. The code is written only for 2 arrays.

**The content of $pvid:**

```
00088da343b00d9b
00088da38100f93c
```

**The content of $hdaix:**

```
hdisk0
hdisk1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in:

```
push @{ $arrpvid[$pvid] }, $hdaix;
```

The `$pvid` should be a numeric value like 0 or 5 and not i.e. `00088da343b00d9b`

Answer (score 2):

#### Quick Fix

Looks like you want to use a hash rather than an array, making your inner `push`

```
push @{ $arrpvid{$pvid} }, $hdaix;
```

Note the change from square brackets to curly braces immediately surrounding `$pvid`. This tells the compiler that you want `%arrpvid` and not `@arrpvid`, so be sure to tweak your `my` declaration as well.

At the end to print the contents of `%arrpvid`, use

```
foreach my $pvid (sort { hex $a <=> hex $b } keys %arrpvid) {
  local $" = "][";  # handy trick due to mjd
  print "$pvid: [@{$arrpvid{$pvid}}]\n";
}
```

The [Data::Dumper](http://perldoc.perl.org/Data/Dumper.html) module is quick and easy output tool.

```
use Data::Dumper;

$Data::Dumper::Indent = $Data::Dumper::Terse = 1;
print Dumper \%arrpvid;
```

#### More Details

You might be tempted to obtain the numeric value corresponding to each hexadecimal string in `$pvid` with [`hex`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/hex.html) as in

```
push @{ $arrpvid[hex $pvid] }, ...
```

but given the large example values in your question, `@arrpvid` would become enormous. Use a hash to create a [sparse array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_array) instead.

Be sure that all the values of `$pvid` have the same padding. Otherwise, like values may not hash together appropriately. If you need to normalize, use code along the lines of

```
$pvid = sprintf "%016x", hex $pvid;
```