# Perl: Populate 2D Array of Unknown Length with Multiline Data

Tags: arrays, perl, multidimensional-array, multiline

### Background

I have a Perl program that is going through directories and parsing text files for certain information. One such piece of information is the Analysis Block, which looks like this:

```
*ANALYSIS_START* [analysis ID]
  Line(s)     = [multi- or single-line Line(s) data]
  Reason Code = [single-line Reason Code data]
  CR          = [single-line CR data]
  Note        = [multi-line Note data]
                [multi-line Note data]
*ANALYSIS_END*
```

A text file can have *zero* Analysis Blocks, or it may have *any number* of these Analysis Blocks - the number of blocks and the size of each are unknown. What I'm hoping to do is to gather the information within these blocks in a 2D array. For example, if a text file had exactly 2 Analysis Blocks, the 2D array would look something like this:

```
$VAR1 = [
            [                                       
                Lines       = [multi- or single-line data]
                Reason Code = [single-line data]
                CR          = [single-line data]
                Note        = [multi-line data]
                              [multi-line data]
            ]                                       
            [                                       
                Lines       = [multi- or single-line data]
                Reason Code = [single-line data]
                CR          = [single-line data]
                Note        = [multi-line data]
                              [multi-line data]
            ]                                       
        ];
```

If someone has a better suggestion for gathering data while keeping each Analysis Block together as shown above, let me know. There may be a better solution than a 2D array that I'm unaware of.

### Attempt

I'm fairly new to Perl, but I understand how to create a 2D array by looking at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/317310/how-can-i-create-multidimensional-arrays-in-perl). The problem is that I'm not sure how to populate a 2D array with my specific case. So far, I have the following code:

```
while (my $current_line = <$textfile>) {

    # Code that gets other, single-line information from file

    $pattern = '\*ANALYSIS_START\*';
    if ($current_line =~ $pattern) {       # Find Analysis Block
        push @analysis_IDs, $1;            # Get the analysis ID
        while(<$textfile>) {
            last if /\*ANALYSIS_END\*/;    # Stop at block's end
            push @analysis_info, $_;       # Append each line of data
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, this causes my array to look something like this, where each line of the file is separate but the Analysis Blocks are not:

```
$VAR1 = ''
$VAR2 = 'Lines       = [lines data]'
$VAR3 = 'Reason Code = [reason code data]'
$VAR4 = 'CR          = [cr data]'
$VAR5 = 'Note        = [note data]'
$VAR6 = '              [note data...]'
$VAR7 = ''
$VAR8 = 'Lines       = [lines data]'
$VAR9 = 'Reason Code = [reason code data]'
$VAR10= 'CR          = [cr data]'
$VAR11= 'Note        = [note data]'
$VAR12= '              [note data...]'
```

### Question

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around how to iterate through each section of the file in order to create the desired 2D array. I've probably just been staring at it too long.

How can I create the array I need? All explanations, word-only or those with code examples, are very much appreciated.

---

*Can my question be improved? Please let me know in the comments!*

Comment: That looks *really* close to [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) which would be very easy to parse. I don't suppose you can change the format to JSON?

Comment: @Schwern Does that require changing the format of the data within the text documents? If so, then unfortunately that is something I cannot change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to get what the question asks for, in particular by using array of arrays.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $file = 'data_analysis.txt';
open my $fh, '<', $file or die "Can't open $file -- $!";

# Prepare (and compile) START/END paterns, capturing ID in START
my $start_pattern = qr|\*ANALYSIS_START\*\s*\[([^[]+)\]|;
my $end_pattern   = qr(\*ANALYSIS_END\*);

my @analysis_IDs;
my @analysis_info;

while (my $line = <$fh>) 
{
    chomp($line);

    # Code that gets other, single-line information from file

    if ($line =~ $start_pattern .. $line =~ $end_pattern) 
    {   
        if ($line =~ $start_pattern) {
            push @analysis_IDs, $1;    # Get the analysis ID
            push @analysis_info, [];   # Add arrayref this block's lines
        }   
        elsif (not $line =~ $end_pattern) {
            push @{$analysis_info[-1]}, $line;  # add to last []
        }
    }   
}

print "$_\n" for @analysis_IDs;

use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper(\@analysis_info);
```

The code uses the range operator `..` to determine when it is inside the patterns. This useful operator keeps the state across iterations so it knows when a condition has been satisfied and is still true (or not). It evaluates true once the first condition becomes (and stays) true, as long as the second one stays false. This saves us from maintaining a separate variable to keep track of all that. See [Range Operators in perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators). Since start and end patterns need a different treatment, they are distinguished (again) inside. This is not the most efficient way but I am hoping that it is clear.

Matching may use `$line =~ $pattern` instead of `$line =~ /$pattern/` since the used patterns had been prepared with `qr`.  An explicit `$line` is used in quest for clarity but one can just (implicitly) use `$_` which provides for more compact code.  In particular, the range condition simplifies to `(/$start_pattern/ .. /$end_pattern/)`, where we now do need delimiters. A nearly any delimiter (or a pair) can be used, which holds for `qr` operator as well. See [Quote-like operators in perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators). Note that I use `qr|...|` in the first case above so that `()` can be used freely inside, what isn't possible in the second one since they *are* the delimiters. Standard regex docs are -- tutorial [perlretut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html), quick introduction [perlrequick](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick.html), full syntax [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html), and reference [perlreref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreref.html).

With this approach you keep a separate array with analysis ID and another one with blocks, as asked.  They agree by indices, but that may not be a most reliable system.

Instead, a hash of arrays can be used, for example. Then an anonymous array for a block's content would be a 'value' for the key which is the ID. In this case you wouldn't have an order maintained though. That can be solved with another auxilliary structure, for example, if needed.

Here is a tutorial about [Arrays of Arrays](http://perldoc.perl.org/perllol.html) and a cookbook on [Complex Data structures](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html).

Comment: Thank you! I had seen ranged operators used before but did not know they could be used this way. :)

Comment: What is the difference between `qr|regex|` and `qr(regex)`? I don't see either of those delimiters in the [perlop documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators)

Comment: @Kimbluey  These range operators are sometimes exactly what you need :).  There is no difference in delimiters -- you can use practically any. The docs just don't list all that, but note the sentence from your link -- _...a `{}` represents any pair of delimiters you choose_. It is pretty much like for a normal regex, where you can even do: `$var =~ s{pattern}{repl}`. This can be extremely helpful.  I'll add a note on this to the post.

Comment: Thanks! One last question, if I may: Later in my program, I need to get each piece of information from every Analysis Block...long story short, I'm iterating through the array of arrays and I'm having trouble saving the multi-line Note data to a single variable. As I'm iterating, I'm looking for `Note\s+=(\s+.*)`, but of course that just gets the first line of each note. How can I grab all Note data from `Note = [note data]` to the end of the sub-array (where Note's data ends)? Is there an easy way to say, "If you find Note, grab this and all following values 'til the sub-array's end"?

Comment: I'm trying to bring each line of the Note data together into one long string variable per Analysis Block, e.g. `$note = [note data line1] . [note data line 2] . [...] . [note data line n]`

Comment: (Let me know if that's too big a question to ask and answer in comments)

Comment: @Kimbluey  OK, so now you are processing what is in the array, line by line (what range saved us from above :). (1) You can set a flag when you hit 'Note' and merge lines when the flag is true. Say you are looping over `@analysis_info`. Then `@block = @{$analysis_info[$i]}; $is_note = 0; for $line (@block) { if ($line =~ /^\s*Note/) { $is_note = 1; };  if ($is_note) { $note_text .= $line }; }`. This relies on the 'Note' ending with array (no other lines following).  Add `my` etc.  _Check this_, it's tricky to type code here.  (2) Or, you could again use the range operator :)

Comment: @Kimbluey  A bit big for a comment, yes, but I tried.  You nicely raised a question about other approaches, and yes there are (of course), but what to choose depends on exactly what you need to do with data afterwards.  If there is more and more processing to do and it gets hairy this way you may want to reconsider the array-of-arrays.  That may well be another good question (also see the perldsc link in my post).

Comment: Okay, thank you very much! Yea, it probably looks weird that I'm collecting the data in an array-of-arrays and _then_ separating everything out anyway, but unfortunately with all the other things my program must do I am required to D: Thanks again!

Comment: @Kimbluey Well, it doesn't look weird -- it's a reasonable way to store lines (and process them later).  It (always) depends on what you do with data.  Another possibly useful way to keep these would be in a hash, `{'Lines' => 'string', 'Reason' => 'string', ... }`. This is convenient since you can then retrieve them by name. (Can keep references to these hashes in an array, for example.)  However, it may be far better to just have arrays that you cleanly iterate over.  It depends.

Answer (score 0):

All you should need is another array for the blocks.  You then push this onto your main array when you hit the next one or the final block.

```
my @analysis_Ids;
my $current_analysis = [];
while (my $current_line = <$textfile>) {
    push @$current_analysis, $_;
    # if next one, push @analysis_Ids, $current_analysis; and reset $current_analysis;
}
# check for the final one.
```